# Does the Medic need to wait until their next turn to remove cubes when another player researches a cure?

Tags: pandemic

Say Medic got to Paris with 3 blue cubes but didn't have enough action to remove cubes, and a next player cures blue. Do we get to remove those blue cubes from Paris right away or do we wait till Medic's next turn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandemic: The Medic and cured diseases](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/pandemic-the-medic-and-cured-diseases)

Comment: @SQB I don't think they are duplicates. This is about when a medic's ability kicks in after another player researches a cure, whereas the other question is about how the medic's ability works during the medic's turn.  I've modified the question titles of both to better clarify what they were asking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The blue cubes in Paris are removed immediately:

From [the Rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/27536/pandemic-rules-permission-z-man-games) (Classic Pandemic p.5), emphasis mine:

> The Medic removes all cubes, not 1, of the same color when doing the Treat Disease action. **If a disease has been cured, he automatically removes all cubes of that color from a city, simply by entering it or being there**. This does not take an action.
>   The Medic also prevents placing disease cubes (and outbreaks) of cured
>   diseases in his location. **The Medic's automatic removal of cubes also
>   happens during other players' turns**.

Comment: As @beewee said, you should accept this answer if it helped. I know it helped me, I wasn't aware that this was even in the rules. Nice answer.

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to do that till now. Thanks again beewee, and to you as well John!

Comment: Thanks for that! In fact, that's one of the core princips of the site ;-) Take the Quick tour: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour you'll even get a badge for that ;-)